# CSS cant center menu and empty space in sub-menu 2nt row

Tags: html, css

I'm working on CSS on webshop https://amres.manoverskis.lt/. And having a bad time with the menu bar. First of all, I can't centre it out. And the 2nd problem I have is that when you hover on the first menu item (PAVEIKSLAI) sub-menu appears and the first item in that menu is more left than the 2nd one. I can't seem to find what is wrong with it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add:

```
#hor-menu {
display:flex;
justify-content:center
}
```

and

```
#hor-menu>.grid_60 {
display:flex;
justify-content:center
}
```

to center the menu

and to remove the left gap in sub-menu, reset margins in ul:

```
.fs2 {
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
#hor-menu { 
padding-left: 25%;
}
```

and change the class of UL for the second submenu (**fs2 grid_12  omega submenu-2-column submenu-2-column-2**) to > (**fs2 grid_12 alpha  submenu-2-column submenu-2-column-1**)

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 examples for you. I hope it'll help you out.

1 - If you want navigation left align in your content area.

```
#hor-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

2 - If you want the navigation to align in the center on your screen.

```
#hor-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and changes grid class name in your HTML from `<div class="grid_60">` to `<div class="grid_0">`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
#main-menu { /* center menu */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content-wrap ul#main-menu li a {
  text-align: left; /* fix menu item */
}
```

To center menu you can simply make it flex, now most browsers support it.

And in your navigation second item was just aligned center so it looked like margin.